# Pandas & python TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset looks something like this:

```
    film_title      writers        actors

0                                  Leonardo Dicaprio, Jason Statham, Dwayne Johnson...
1                                  Jack Nicholson, Robert De Niro, Denzel Washington...
2                                  Jack Nicholson, Jason Statham, Dwayne Johnson...
```

'...' signifies that there are more actors in that cell; I am trying to put all the actors in a list(and not include duplicates). So far I have the following code:

```
actorsList = df_final.actors.str.split(', ') #which splits the cells into multiple lists

#print(actorsList) will print this:
['Leonardo Dicaprio', 'Jason Statham', 'Dwayne Johnson'...]
['Jack Nicholson', 'Robert De Niro', 'Denzel Washington'...]
['Jack Nicholson', 'Jason Statham', 'Dwayne Johnson'...]
```

so

```
print(actorsList[0]) #will print the first list: ['Leonardo Dicaprio', 'Jason Statham', 'Dwayne Johnson'...]
```

I am then trying to iterate through this list again, and store every actor name(not duplicates as they can appear in multiple films)

```
#ITERATE THROUGH ONE LIST
for i in range(len(actorsList[0])):
    txt = actorsList[0][i].split(', ')
    print(txt)
```

This prints something like this:

```
['Leonardo Dicaprio']
['Jason Statham']
['Dwayne Johnson']
and so on
```

I am trying to do this for every list there is, however, I end up getting this error:

```
       23 for i in range(len(actorsList)-1):
  ---> 24     for j in range(len(actorsList[i])):
       25         txt = actorsList[i][j].split(', ')
       26         print(txt)

       TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

I should also mention the fact that it runs (prints results), however, it stops and then I get this error.

Comment: what is the output of `print(actorsList)`?

Comment: Check below: ` actorsList = df_final.actors.str.split(', ')`

Comment: Using just those three lines the script works fine, that's why I'm asking. Maybe after the third element there is something fishy